# Cambiar formato de fecha con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array, datetime

Estoy utilizando este código como ejemplo:

```
let curr = new Date 
let week = []

for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i 
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  week.push(day)
}
```

El programa me devuelve al imprimir la variable week esto:
2022-01-24,2022-01-25,2022-01-26,2022-01-27,2022-01-28,2022-01-29,2022-01-30

Cómo puede convertir el formato de los valores al array para que se vean así 24/01/2022, 25/01/2022, 26/01/2022, 27/01/2022, 28/01/2022, 29/01/2022, 30/01/2022,

En resumen cómo cambio el formato para que se vea en esa orden d m año con un "/" entre cada numero

Comment: Prueba con [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo como solución, reemplazar los '-' por '/' de la siguiente forma:

```
let newFormat = week.map(day => day.split('-').reverse().join('/'));
```

Utilizamos el método `split` para dividir el string a partir del carácter '-' y obtener un array de strings, luego utilizamos el método `reverse` para invertir el orden del array y por ultimo unimos todo con el método `join` concatenando el carácter '/'

Comment: Gracias Nicolas, lo del "/" me funciono bien para mi primer problema, pero como comenta masterguru  tengo que cambiar el formato a dia mes año  o sea asi se vería el array 24/01/2022 etc

Comment: tenes razon @masterguru, ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: @user17608147, edite la respuesta para invertir el orden, utilizando el método `reverse`

Comment: excelente gracias. s

Comment: Perfecto, ahora esta bien :-)  Gracias, no conocia esa funcion del reverse aun

Comment: @user17608147 Si esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que conste y no quede pendiente para siempre. Esta bien agradecerlo, pero aqui lo agradecemos aceptando las respuestas válidas, gracias